# Cassandra 2.2.0 installation on macbook

Tags: cassandra-2.0

I am trying to install Cassandra 2.2.0, but the screen is getting hung with the below message -

INFO  14:55:12 Starting listening for CQL clients on localhost/127.0.0.1:9042...
INFO  14:55:12 Binding thrift service to localhost/127.0.0.1:19160
INFO  14:55:12 Listening for thrift clients...

As a workaround I tried;
1) updating rpc_port to : 19160 from current :9160
2) start_rpc: true from existing start_rpc: false

Comment: How exactly is the screen hung? "Listening for thrift clients" is the last message shown when the cassandra node is up and running so it sounds like the node is running. What did you use to run the server?

Comment: its working now, but when I connect cqlsh its giving an error - "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "bin/cqlsh.py", line 1150, in perform_simple_statement
    rows = future.result(self.session.default_timeout)
TypeError: result() takes exactly one argument (2 given)"

Comment: despite the above error, I am able to create key space, and table, but I am not able to insert data

Comment: Which version of Python do you have installed? Cassandra requires Python 2.7.